# R: Only Displaying a Certain Part of a Geographical Map

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I am using the built-in geographical shapefile for the map of the different counties within North Carolina:

```
library(sf)
library(igraph)
library(ggplot2)

nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
    st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>% 
    st_cast('POLYGON')
```

**My Problem:** Suppose I take Duke University - I am interested in only visualizing the county in which Duke University is located, all neighboring counties of that county, all neighboring counties of the neighboring counties, and all neighboring counties of the neighboring counties of the neighboring counties (i.e. degree 3)

To solve this problem, I first located the county in which Duke University is located:

```
duke_point <- st_point(x = c(-78.9382, 36.0014)) %>%
  st_sfc(crs = 4326)

county_name <- lapply(1:nrow(nc), function(j) {
  nc[which(st_intersects(duke_point, nc[j, ], sparse = FALSE)), ]$NAME
}) %>% unlist()
```

Then, I converted the shapefile into a network graph:

```
adj_matrix <- st_touches(nc, sparse = FALSE)
nc_graph <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj_matrix)
```

Next, I located the county which contains Duke University:

```
index <- which(nc$NAME == "Ashe")
node_number <- V(nc_graph)[index]
```

After that, I found all neighbors of degree 3  for this county:

```
index <- which(nc$NAME == "Ashe")

node_number <- V(nc_graph)[index]

neighbors_3 <- ego(nc_graph, order = 3, nodes = node_number, mode = "all")[[1]]
```

Finally, I made a visualization:

```
    indices <- as.numeric(neighbors_3)
    nc$highlight <- ifelse(1:nrow(nc) %in% indices, "yes", "no")
    nc_2 <- nc[nc$highlight == "yes", ]

center_lat <- 36.0014
center_lon <- -78.9382,


x_range <- 0.5
y_range <- 0.5


duke_label <- data.frame(lon = center_lon, lat = center_lat, label = "Duke University")

ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = nc,
            aes(fill = highlight),
            alpha = 0.8,
            colour = 'white',
            size = 0.3) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("yes" = "red", "no" = "grey"),
                      name = "Highlight") +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL,
         title = "Highlighting counties in North Carolina") +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
          line = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.title = element_blank()) +
    coord_sf(datum = NA)
```

[image]

**My Question:** Just to confirm, have I done this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is one of those questions where you'll know as well as / better than anyone else whether this is "correct," since it depends on what you want. For one thing, there are different ways of defining neighbors in spatial analysis--you've chosen one, which is no more correct than any others. You might have a better time using functions specific to spatial neighbors, like from `spdep` or `rgeoda`. Also, is the plot part of what you're asking about, or just for illustration?

Comment: I would double check, I believe Duke and Raleigh/Durham is further east than what your map is showing.

Comment: @ Camille: thank you for your feedback! I was thinking that the plot could be used to validate the R code I wrote. For example, I wanted all polygons (i.e. counties) of degree = 3 that border the polygon containing Duke University. If I highlight all polygons with degree=3 ... I can then informally check to see if any of the highlighted polygons have have more than degree 3.

Comment: @ Dave2e: thank you for your reply! I am not very familiar with the geography of North Carolina as I live in a different country :( . Do you think I have made a mistake? If you have time, could you please show me how to correct this? Thank you so much!